# Where are gdb-multiarch sources?

Tags: gdb, open-source

I've been struggling a hour to find the git repository of gdb-multiarch but couldn't succeed. Is the source available somewhere ?

Answer (score 3):

GDB's web site is [here](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/), the page that describes source access is [here](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/current/).  Basically for read-only access you want:

```
git clone https://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
```

Comment: `gdb-multiarch` is "just GDB" configured to support multiple architectures.

Comment: Okay thanks, and do you know whether the configuration file is available or not ?

Comment: If you want to configure exactly how a particular distro does then you'd need to check how that particular package is built.  In general, for a multi-target GDB configure using `--enable-targets=all` along with any other configure options you need.

Comment: For Debian, see https://sources.debian.org/src/gdb/12.1-4/debian/rules/#L200

Comment: @HellDiner you can see how GDB was configured at build time with `show configuration` command.